# Mapping parameter for special characters

Tags: informatica

I need to remove special characters like \r,\n in informatica using mapping parameter. When I am giving \r, \n in mapping parameter it is not getting populated correctly for multiple values

Answer (score 0):

I do not think they can be passed using parameter like \n,\r.
You can use chr() functionality and use ASCII values.

For line feed,pass 10 in parameter. And use it like below in expression transformation -

```
REPLACESTR(1,STRING_PORT,chr($$Param1),'')
```

For carriage return, pass 13.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. In paramfile it is not taking multiple values

Comment: How to declare multiple special characters in paramfile $$param1

Comment: You need to declare multiple parameters in the mapping. carriage return, use $$Param2, for line feed $$Param1 and so on. You can get  ascii values for your special characters in https://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/ascii-codes/